# Change NestJs logger type to console on specific controller/API instead of global

Tags: logging, nestjs

I'm trying to change the logger type of NestJs to use the built-in global JavaScript `console` object. Referring to this documentation: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/logger This can be done in main.ts:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
  logger: console,
});
await app.listen(3000);
```

However, there is a concern that this might bloat up the pm2 log file. Is there a way to scope it down to the controller or specific API?

For example (in a specific API):

```
const logger = new Logger("context", {
  // set options here? but only seems to have timestamp       
});
logger.debug(`bla bla`);
```

Or set in controller level:

```
export class CatController{
  logger: Logger;  

  constructor() {    
    this.logger = new Logger(CatController.name); // set to console??
  }
```

Comment: One solution would be to create your own logger class, https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/logger#custom-implementation, then create methods for `console.log` and methods for your other logging mechanism